# What does mappedInterceptors do in SimpleUrlHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I have an application running on SpringFramework version 3.0, it uses SimpleUrlHandlerMapping bean to map the requests to controllers. It has the following properties set [ order, mappings, interceptors, mappedInterceptors ].

I understand that interceptors can be used for pre/post handling of the requests. But i dont understand the purpose of mappedInterceptors. I could not find any documentation explaining this. The Spring-3.0.x doc doesnt explain on this either (http://tinyurl.com/kcuwp8h
). SimpleUrlHandlerMapping in Spring 3.1 doesnt even have this property.

Can someone pls tell me what is it used for? and How is it achieved in Spring 3.1 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 3.1 `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` inherits the property from `AbstractHandlerMapping`.

`MappedInterceptor` is just a wrapper for `HandlerInterceptor` and can be used to restrict the execution of an interceptor to a certain request path.

I don't know if Spring currently uses this feature at all. The source code does not show any usage. That would explain the lack of documentation.